# Why can not access to pointer object of _User in Parse?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have a table called "Event" with public read and write access.
Inside this table I have one field called "user". This field is a pointer to _User table with public read and only user write access.

This is my code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.objID];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.objID block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {

        PFUser *host = [object objectForKey:@"user"];
        NSLog(@"HOST == %@",host);
        self.hostId = host.objectId;
     }
]);
```

Now problem is, if userA create a row in Event table called eventA and userB create an Event called eventB. if UserA query eventB cannot access to userB information. However, if userA query eventA, it can access to itself information.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is pretty much easy. It seems that I need to include key in my query:

```
[query includeKey:@"user"];
```